# In application gateway "Backend certificate is invalid", Do really require by app gateway to monitored the validity of backend server certificate?

Tags: azure-application-gateway

In application gateway "Backend certificate is invalid", Do really require by app gateway to monitored the validity of backend server certificate?
As because we have seen due to this human error can be encounter, whereas application owner and Azure administrator should be aware of the working flow of the application. But although the certificate is invalid to-and-fro communication would be secure, hence its worthless of mentioning "HTTPS connection won't be secure unless the server's TLS/SSL certificate is valid" in Azure portal.

However now a days every organization looking for cost saving, whereas Administrators are working in shared model and if any production application missed to update certificate in-between, can cause the business loss.

Rather MS has to introduce server certificate profile in http setting, which accepts the default certificate no matter valid or invalid and monitoring only the secure connection for end-to-end encryption.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-backend-health-troubleshooting

Comment: Please share your feedback or idea /suggestion in https://feedback.azure.com

Answer (score 0):

Currently, for the TLS connection to work in Application gateway, you need to ensure that the TLS/SSL certificate meets the following conditions:

1. That the current date and time is within the "Valid from" and "Valid
   to" date range on the certificate.
2. That the certificate's "Common Name" (CN) matches the host header in the request. For example, if the client is making a request to https://www.contoso.com/, then the CN must be [www.contoso.com](http://www.contoso.com).

Refer : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/ssl-overview

If the Trusted Root Certificate uploaded is expired or backend server certificate’s Common Name (CN) does not match with the Hostname entered in HTTP Settings, the probe (default or custom) will start marking the backend servers as Unhealthy so that the requests won’t be routed to them.

There is no other way available to get this working at the moment. If you wish you may leave your feedback in the below forum requesting the desired feature. All the feedback you share in these forums will be monitored and reviewed by the Microsoft engineering teams responsible for building Azure.
https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/8ae9bf04-8326-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0789